# Break list into nested lists based on criteria

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested

I have a list in a list similar to this but much longer:

```
master_list=[[foo, fum, A, fee, 5, see, V, G],[B, foo, flo, 6, lee, D, 8, 9]]
```

I wish the break the lists within this nested list into their own nested lists. If an element in the list is within a separate list, it would be included in a nested list. Otherwise, it would be left out. So:

```
elements=[foo, fum, 5, flo, lee, D, V]
```

I would end up with the following:

```
final_list=[[[foo, fum], A, fee, [5], see, [V], G],[B, [foo, flo], 6, [lee, D], 8, 9]]
```

I tried this, but it didn't work well:

```
final_list=[]
for master in master_test:
    result = []
    temp_list = []
    for i in master:
        if i in cols:
            temp_list.append(i)
            result.append(temp_list) 
        else:
            temp_list = [] 
            result.append(i)
    result.append(temp_list)
    final_list.append(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

With the `itertools.groupby` standard library function and a generator:

```
from itertools import groupby


def group_by_elements(l, elements):
    for flag, group in groupby(l, lambda x: x in elements):
        if flag:
            yield list(group)
        else:
            yield from group


master_test = [
    ["foo", "fum", "A", "fee", 5, "see", "V", "G"],
    ["B", "foo", "flo", 6, "lee", "D", 8, 9],
]
elements = ["foo", "fum", 5, "flo", "lee", "D", "V"]

print([list(group_by_elements(m, elements)) for m in master_test])
```

This outputs

```
[
  [['foo', 'fum'], 'A', 'fee', [5], 'see', ['V'], 'G'],
  ['B', ['foo', 'flo'], 6, ['lee', 'D'], 8, 9],
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```py
master_test = [
    ["foo", "fum", "A", "fee", 5, "see", "V", "G"],
    ["B", "foo", "flo", 6, "lee", "D", 8, 9]
]
cols = ["foo", "fum", 5, "flo", "lee", "D", "V"]

final_list = []
for master in master_test:
    result = []
    temp_list = []
    for i in master:
        if i in cols:
            temp_list.append(i)
        else:
            if temp_list:
                result.append(temp_list)
            temp_list = []
            result.append(i)
    if temp_list:
        result.append(temp_list)
    final_list.append(result)

print(final_list)
```

Had to do 2 changes:

1. Move `result.append(temp_list)` from `if i in cols` to the else statement and add a checker for empty list
2. Add an empty list checker to the `result.append(temp_list)` after the `for i in master` loop

Comment: `if len(temp_list)` simplifies to `if temp_list`.

Answer (score 0):

`groupby` is the best tool for this.  You can use it in a comprehension that builds the sublists based on presence of master items in the elements list:

```
from itertools import groupby

master = [
    ["foo", "fum", "A", "fee", 5, "see", "V", "G"],
    ["B", "foo", "flo", 6, "lee", "D", 8, 9],
]
elems = ["foo", "fum", 5, "flo", "lee", "D", "V"]


final = [ [r for nest,(*g,) in groupby(m,key=elems.__contains__) 
             for r in [g,[g]][nest] ]
          for m in master ]

print(final)
[ 
  [['foo', 'fum'], 'A', 'fee', [5], 'see', ['V'], 'G'], 
  ['B', ['foo', 'flo'], 6, ['lee', 'D'], 8, 9] 
]
```